# Calling Compile().DynamicInvoke within an extension method causes a "target of an invocation" error in WPF, but not WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, extension-methods

I have an extension that works in WinForms and I'm trying to get it to work in WPF, but it's throwing the following exception when ic all .Compile().DynamicInvoke().

[image: Error Screenshot]

Here is how I'm calling the method:

```
spDetailControls.InvokeThreadSafeMethod(() => spDetailControls.Children.Add(_generalDetail));
```

And here is the extension method:

```
public static void InvokeThreadSafeMethod(this System.Windows.FrameworkElement control, Expression<Action> method)
{
    if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        var del = new InvokeThreadSafeMethodDelegate(InvokeThreadSafeMethod);
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(del, control, method);
    }
    else
    {
        method.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```

Is there something else I should be calling in WPF? Or something else I'm missing?

EDIT:

Per LucasTrzesniewski's suggestion, I changed Expression to just Action. It no longer throws that error, but instead throws a cross thread exception error. The whole point of this extension method is so that it can be called within a background thread.

Here's the changed code. It's likely that I changed something wrong

```
public static void InvokeThreadSafeMethod(this System.Windows.FrameworkElement control, Action method)
{
    if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(new InvokeThreadSafeMethodDelegate(InvokeThreadSafeMethod), control, method);
    else
        method.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

I had to change the delegate as well:

```
private delegate void InvokeThreadSafeMethodDelegate(System.Windows.FrameworkElement control, Action method);
```

Comment: Why use `Expression<Action>` instead of `Action`? Looks like incorrect (useless) use of expression trees for me.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski The code wasn't originally designed for WPF. I'm going to change it to Action and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how the `method` accesses the `control` here, so the cross-thread exception may mean that there is some other control actually accessed when `method` is called, please show an example of calling to `InvokeThreadSafeMethod` (obviously 1 argument of `Action` is required).

Comment: Why are you using `DynamicInvoke` on an `Action`?  Just invoke it directly.  You only need `DynamicInvoke` when you don't have a concrete delegate instance, i.e., when your callback is actually typed as a `Delegate`.

Comment: @KingKing I don't know *exactly* how it works, but it seems that it specially passing action to the method isn't required. Calling it just as I have it in the original thread is that that's needed. Which is exactly how it works in WinForms.

Comment: you should at least know where you call to `InvokeThreadSafeMethod`, such as `someControl.InvokeThreadSafeMethod(someAction)`, what we care about here is the detailed code of `someAction`. For the naming convention, `someAction` should be some method of `someControl`, if it's the case, it should work but I doubt it's not the case. You might pass in some other method accessing to any other control (not `someControl`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension method is unnecessarily complicated, and may be obfuscating an error originating in your delegate.  This is all you need:

```
public static void InvokeThreadSafeMethod(
    this System.Windows.FrameworkElement control,
    Action method)
{
    if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        method();
    else
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(method);
}
```

If you're getting a cross-thread exception while using the implementation above, then your delegate is probably touching a UI element that was created on a different thread than `control`.

For example, if this is your actual code:

```
spDetailControls.InvokeThreadSafeMethod(
    () => spDetailControls.Children.Add(_generalDetail));
```

...then maybe you `_generalDetail` on a background thread?

Comment: The same cross thread error occurs with this exact code: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Then something else is going on.  We need to see the exact stack trace, as well as all inner exceptions and their stack traces.  Also, can you show us which code you're executing with this method?  If it's the example in your original post, did you create `_generalDetail` on a background thread?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: It definitely seems like an issue with spDetailControls, which is a stack panel on the main UI. _generalDetail is a control that's bein added to the StackPanel. It's also on the UI thread. But the errors still occurs if _generalDetail is declare within the background thread. I'm trying to gather more debugging data at the moment.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your lambda body, and compare `.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId` for `spDetailControls` and `_generalDetail`.

Comment: Huh. I guess they are on different threads. The IDs were different. I had forgotten that _generalDetail was declared in the main code behind, but was instantiated in the background thread. The problem appears resolved when I instantiate _generalDetail in the UI thread . Thanks!

Comment: Yep, controls can only interact with controls that are created on the same thread.